# Login issue in Beaglebone Black using Linux Kernel 4.4.115 and systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, beagleboneblack, buildroot

I managed to compile with success the Uboot(U-Boot 2019.04), Linux kernel(4.4.155)and root file system(systemd 249) using the Buildroot-2021.11.1 on the Beaglebone Black. It was able to boot successfully until the login prompt. However, it seems like there is an error with the login prompt it does not want to enter, just looping around the login prompt after I have entered the login name (not showing the password prompt). Did anyone know about this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.

I have missed out 2 important settings in Buildroot menuconfig menu which is BR2_PACKAGE_SYSTEMD_LOGIND and BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_LOGIN.

These two (or at least one) need to be set in order to login to the system properly.

Thank you

Comment: This is odd, login should work out of the box without enabling extra packages. Could you report this on bugs.busybox.net/ ?